# Migration to create different databases structures in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 different organizations types and 3 different databases structures: one for each type. When org1 registers I'm creating a new database instance for org1, and when org2 registers I'm creating a new db instance, and same for org3.

Now, how do I run migrations for three different db:structure from my application soon after I create a new database instance for organizations.

I am creating a db instance from application by:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

How can I do this? Is there another approach I should be using?

Answer (score 1):

The command you are looking for is establish_connection.  You might
want to look at the rails rdoc.  Search for "Connection to multiple
databases in different models" in 
http://api.rubyonrails.com/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html.

Connections are usually created through ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection and retrieved by ActiveRecord::Base.connection. All classes inheriting from ActiveRecord::Base will use this connection. But you can also set a class-specific connection. For example, if Course is an ActiveRecord::Base, but resides in a different database, you can just say Course.establish_connection and Course and all of its subclasses will use this connection instead.